# Unable to locate addons button in firefox android app using selenium java with appium

Tags: selenium, appium

Selenium is unable to locate the addons buttons on firefox android app. I have tried both id and xpath locator.

Here is the code snippet:

```
// driver is an instance of AndroidDriver
driver.navigate().to("about:addons");
Thread.sleep(5000);

WebElement mainLayout = driver.findElementById("org.mozilla.firefox:id/main_layout");
System.out.println("#" + mainLayout.getText());

WebElement addonsList = driver.findElementById("addons-list");
System.out.println("@" + addonsList);

MobileElement randomUserAgent = (MobileElement) addonsList.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[5]"));
System.out.println(randomUserAgent);
```

[image]

[image]

I am able to open the addons page, but after that I am getting following error (not able to find element with id "addons-list"):

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
```

Can anyone help me to locate and clcik on the addons button.
Thanks

Comment: Access the buttons directly, not through the frame element.

Comment: I have tried accessing the buttons directly, but same result.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather to change user-agent at mobile firefox another way: by changing preferences of browser by hand:

1. Open a new tab and enter the following text in the address bar:

about:config

2. Enter the following text in the search box:

general.useragent.overridepreference

3. If you don't have the value general.useragent.overridepreference, create it yourself. Right-click on the about:config page, and go to New -> String in the context menu.

More detail [here](https://winaero.com/blog/change-user-agent-firefox/).